# How can I formalize the following sentence into first-order logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Every by $10$ divisible number is ending by the digit $0$.

My solution:

let be $N(x)$ a natural number, which is divisible by $10$,

let be $L(x)$ the last digit of a number

$( \forall x)( N(x) \implies L(x)) $

and the negation of it is:

$ (\exists x)( \neg N(x) \implies \neg L(x)).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first symbolization is correct, but for the negation of it, please note that the $\neg$ does not distribute over the $\Rightarrow$. That is:

$$\neg (P \Rightarrow Q) \not \equiv \neg P \Rightarrow \neg Q$$

But rather:

$$\neg (P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv \neg (\neg P \lor Q) \equiv \neg \neg P \land \neg Q \equiv P \land \neg Q$$

As such:

$$\neg ( \forall x)( N(x) \implies L(x)) \equiv ( \exists x)\neg ( N(x) \implies L(x))\equiv ( \exists x)( N(x) \land \neg L(x))$$

Answer (score 3):

For your latter case, the negation would be:

$\exists x$ $(N(x) \wedge \neg L(x) )$

Answer (score 2):

**Always remember:**

- $\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))$ says: "Any thing, *if* $P$, will be $Q$".
- $\exists x~(P(x)\wedge Q(x))$ says: "Some thing, is $P$, *and* also $Q$".

*Also recall* that the negation of implication is a conjunction vis: $\neg (A\to B)\iff A\wedge\neg B$

So:

- "Any (natural)number, divisible by 10, will end in the digit zero."

  > $$\forall x~(N(x)\to L(x))$$
- "Not every (natural)number, divisible by 10, will end in the digit zero."

  "Some (natural)number, divisible by 10, does *not* end in the digit zero."

  > $$\exists x~(N(x)\wedge\neg L(x))$$